# Error in rawQuery of sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I have this query:

```
Cursor c = datasource.db.rawQuery("select * from posts where tags like '%?%' order by time desc",new String[]{arg0});
```

but it gives me this error:

**Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range. The statement has 0 parameters**

I placed the **?** character in my query but rawQuery() doesn't detect it.

What do I have to do now?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `tags like ?` and your `?` being `%some_value%`?

Comment: finaly used @juergen-d solution and problem solved. thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`like '%?%'` - Since you enclosed the parameter placeholder in quotes, it's no longer being treated as a parameter, but as a string, literally.

You want to do so, instead:

```
Cursor c = datasource.db.rawQuery("select * from posts where tags like ?", new String[]{"%" + arg0 + "%"});
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do two things. First:

```
Cursor c = datasource.db.rawQuery("select * from posts where tags like '%" + arg0 + "%' order by time desc", null);
```

Or second:

```
Cursor c = datasource.db.rawQuery("select * from posts where tags like'%' | '?' | '%'", new String[]{arg0});
```

here you could find more possible solutions https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3153

Comment: Only the first one will work (but will fail if arg0 contains a single quote, like `don't`). The second one won't.

Comment: So you suggest not using Prepared Statements and invite SQL injections? Absolutely not!